# Creating enemies, slowing game Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am doing a game, and I got only 1 final problem. Its that when the game create an enemy the FPS slow to 40 or 20. Depends if it creates 1 or 2 enemies.

```
NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"laser_%d.png", i]]];
    }

    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.12f];    
    CCSprite *laser = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"laser_1.png"];

    int tempY = (arc4random() % ((int)(300 - laser.boundingBox.size.height))) + laser.boundingBox.size.height;
    float tempRot = (arc4random() % 30) + 1;
    int sign = (arc4random() % 2) - 1;
    if (sign < 0) {
        tempRot *= -1;
    }

    laser.tag = 2;

    laser.position = ccp(650, tempY);
    laser.rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(tempRot);
    CCAction *walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                            [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:YES]];
    [laser runAction:walkAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:laser];

    b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
    spriteBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    spriteBodyDef.position.Set(laser.position.x/PTM_RATIO, 
                               laser.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
    spriteBodyDef.userData = laser;
    b2Body *spriteBody = world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);

    [[GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache] addShapesWithFile:@"laserBody.plist"];
    [[GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache] addFixturesToBody:spriteBody forShapeName:@"laser_1"];
    [laser setAnchorPoint:[[GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache] anchorPointForShape:@"laser_1"]];

    //pixeles recoridos/velocidad del move actual
    float timeAnim = 800/(60*move);
    [laser runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                      [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:timeAnim position:ccp(-800, 0)],
                      [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(obstaclesDone:)],
                      nil]];
```

I am using Physic Editor, to create the shape. After it create. The game works fine in 60 fps. But only in the iPhone. In my iMac works perfectly.

What could do I do to create it without loosing fps. Maybe in the second processor. Or another thread?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the size and quality of the textures you are using?  It could be that too much memory is required to create sprite instances making it difficult to keep a high frame rate constantly changing the positions of those sprites.  You could also try profiling with Instruments to see what is eating up your processor cycles.

Comment: My laser its about 97k each frames (3). I will run it in instruments and see. Maybe i could do it of about 50k. But 300k for the iPhone it's nothing

Comment: I think instruments said that everything its ok. Virtual memory usage: 121mb real Memory: 10mb. 1 Leak of 16 bytes. 6 threads [on mi imac] and .4% processor about 25% in iPhone. I really see anything weird. I can't test instruments with my iPhone because its disconeccting

Comment: @Ernesto You may want to try lowering the size of your textures just to eliminate this as a possible problem.  I am working on a game where each frame of animation is 12KB.  Not to say that the iPhone couldn't handle it but 97k does seem a bit high for an individual frame of animation.  In instruments you should take a look at the time profiler to get a sense of which functions are taking the longest to execute.

Comment: I was checking all the profiler and I found that when i check the achievements it takes about 100ms or more to check and update. I runic in background and only check it locally only if you complete it and you haven't get it it post it in game center. I think that was the problem. Because i do that and every things works fine again. Thanks :D